# How to use private AWS ECR image from GitLab?

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to use private AWS ECR image as image for GitLab job.

I installed `amazon-ecr-credential-helper` and it is works. I checked it with using Docker from terminal.

I configured GitLab runner with using `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` env variable. But GitLab ignores it. Nor from .gitlab-ci.yml file not from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml.

[image]

Anybody faced the same issue? How to solve?